# Is topical corticosteroid vasoconstriction temporary?

Tags: topical-cream-gel, corticosteroids, dialation, vasoconstriction

If topical corticosteroids cause vasoconstriction, is it always only temporary? Does it always return to its original state or even more dilatated?